# How do I start Edge from the command line with an argument for URL but open it in a new window?

Tags: command-line, microsoft-edge

I'm using `start microsoft-edge:https://www.myURL.ca` to open an Edge browser from CMD. The problem is that I'd like to open it in a new window.

I found the "--new-window" argument which can be used from a structure passed in via C#, but I'm not able to figure out how to get that argument to Edge from CMD.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the command below will help you launch the MS Edge browser new windows from CMD.

```
start msedge www.microsoft.com --new-window
```

Output:

[image]

In the test result, you could notice that there is an existing Edge window. when we run the command it opens a new Edge window.

Comment: Where is this documented?